# Compressing a compiled wxPython program with UPX

Tags: python, wxpython, inno-setup, pyinstaller, upx

I am creating guis with wxPython then compiling them using pyInstaller and finally using inno to set them up.

seeing as i am new to all of this i would like to know, do i need to use UPX to compress just the final compiled exe? or all of the stuff the exe needs to run aswell?

thanks, sorry for being a noob.

Comment: You don't _need_ to compress anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can compress the files before the exe or you'll run into issues of Python not being able to read the zip files. You might be able to use eggs here, but I don't believe eggs are compressed. I would just try compressing the exe with UPX and see how it goes.

I personally don't worry about it. The exe's usually are 20-40 MB and hard disk space is cheap and plentiful.